# Creating file from php radio button variables

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I want to create a text file (or at least to echo) with some values taken from a radio button list.

Looking for info, I have been able to build the radio forms like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Config</title> <!-- Include CSS File Here-->
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
         <!---- Radio Button Starts Here ----->
         <form>
            <label class="heading">First value </label><br>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text1">Value 1 - Option 1<br>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text2">Value 2 - Option 1<br>
         </form>
         <br>
         <form>
            <label class="heading">Second value </label><br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text1">Value 2 - Option 1<br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text2">Value 2 - Option 2<br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text3">Value 2 - Option 3
         </form>
         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I would like to take the values v1 and v2, so I found the following php code (my idea would be to do this with each one of the values):

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['v1']))  
     echo $_POST['v1'];
   else
?>
```

So I added it after the submit button code, however after selecting values and clicking on Submit button nothing happens.

I know nothing about php, the code I have written has been taken from google findings.

Comment: The default method for HTML forms is GET. You are using POST in your PHP code. So you have to add `method="post"` to your `<form>`-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a single form, & place the `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">` inside the `<form>` tag.

We need certain parameters for submitting the form, just like `method` & `action` parameter. Always use '`post`' method for better security.

Now, modify the `<form>` tag with this code:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="">
```

And in 'action' parameter , write the path of the page where you want to submit the form & want to display the values of radio buttons. Just like this

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="results.php">
```

otherwise leave the `action` parameter 'Blank' just like the first `<form>` tag, if you want to submit & get the radio button values on the same page.

Now, the code for retrieving the values of radio buttons:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['v1'])){
        echo $_POST['v1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['v2'])){
        echo $_POST['v2'];
    }
}
?>
```

Place it just above the html tag.

Now, here is your full updated code for proper understanding, just copy & replace with your code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['v1'])){
        echo $_POST['v1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['v2'])){
        echo $_POST['v2'];
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Config</title> <!-- Include CSS File Here-->
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
         <!---- Radio Button Starts Here ----->
         <form method="post" name="form1" action="">
            <label class="heading">First value </label><br>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text1">Value 1 - Option 1<br>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text2">Value 2 - Option 1<br>
            <br/>
            <label class="heading">Second value </label><br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text1">Value 2 - Option 1<br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text2">Value 2 - Option 2<br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text3">Value 2 - Option 3

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you have two forms, and a submit button that submit none of those two.

Also you don't have an endpoint and this assumes that the PHP code is in the same file.

Try something like this

```
<form method="POST" action="./script.php">
    <label class="heading">First value </label><br>
    <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text1">Value 1 - Option 1<br>
    <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text2">Value 2 - Option 1<br>

    <label class="heading">Second value </label><br>
    <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text1">Value 2 - Option 1<br>
    <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text2">Value 2 - Option 2<br>
    <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text3">Value 2 - Option 3

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Config</title> <!-- Include CSS File Here-->
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
         <!---- Radio Button Starts Here ----->
         <form method="post">
            <label class="heading">First value </label><br>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text1">Value 1 - Option 1</input>
            <input name="v1" type="radio" value="v1text2">Value 2 - Option 1</input>

            <label class="heading">Second value </label><br>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text1">Value 2 - Option 1</input>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text2">Value 2 - Option 2</input>
            <input name="v2" type="radio" value="v2text3">Value 2 - Option 3</input>

             <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['v1'])) {
     echo $_POST['v1'];
}
if (isset($_POST['v2'])) {
     echo $_POST['v2'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for printing values.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
      echo "Name:".$key." - Value".$value."<br />";
    }

  }
?>
```